# accessing class objects via typecasting interface ref variable in a package

Tags: java

I am trying to use forName() & newInstance() built-in methods to provide the 
name of the class for which the object will be created to which the interface ref variable will point to. But the compliler keeps throwing the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fclas
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
  at primary.main(primary.java:12)
```

normal reference variable declaration, i.e.

```
 inter1 obj = new fclass();
```

&

```
 inter1 obj = new sclass();
```

seems to work just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated TY.

=============================================================

the interface in package -- program-1

```
package pack1;    //the interface in the package

public interface inter1
{
void print1();
void print2();
}
```

========================================================

//implementation class 1 of interface -- program-2

```
package pack1;
import pack1.inter1;   // the 1st implementation class
import java.io.*;

public class fclass implements inter1
{

      //method bodies

}
```

==========================================================

//implementation class 2 of interface -- program-3

```
package pack1;
import pack1.inter1;     // the 2nd implementation class
import java.io.*;

public class sclass implements inter1
{

   //method bodies

}
```

=========================================================

// the main method -- program 4

```
import pack1.fclass;
import pack1.sclass;
import pack1.inter1;    // the main program
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class primary
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
    String s1 = "fclass";
    Class c = Class.forName(s1);         //THESE 2 LINES R THE PROBLEM
    inter1 obj1 = (inter1)c.newInstance(); // THESE 2 LINES R THE PROBLEM
    obj1.print1();
    obj1.print2();
    inter1 obj = new sclass();    // THIS FORMAT WORKS FINE
    obj.print1();
    obj.print2();
    System.out.println("end..........");
    }
}
```

i am expecting this output:

```
i am print 1 method of package pack1 in fclass
i am print 2 method of package pack1 in fclass
i am print 1 method in package pack1 of sclass
i am print 2 method in package pack1 of sclass
end..........
```

Comment: Read the JavaDoc on `Class.forName(className)` and you should see this: "**className** the fully qualified name of the desired class.". The fully qualified class name includes the package so try `"pack1.fclass"`.

Comment: Btw, please read [ask] (as well as the links at the bottom of that page) and take a general [tour] of SO. You should then realize that lines like "//THESE 2 LINES R THE PROBLEM" could cause downvotes: 1) don't shout and 2) use proper language ("are" instead of "r" etc.)

Comment: yeah sorry for the format it's my first post here so i was "spitballing" . but thanks for the reply it was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

you need to provide the full class name :

```
String s1 = "pack1.fclass";
```

Comment: @Learningman if it worked, please consider accepting the answer :)